# Set background color of Windows 10 File Explorer Preview Pane?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, user-interface, dark-mode, preview-pane

I'm a big fan of dark mode, but I'm severely annoyed by the fact that the Preview Pane of Windows 10 File Explorer is completely white for file like .cpp, .h, .cs, etc... and I looked around the web for a solution that possibly doesn't involve third party plugins or add-ons, but with no avails. [However, I noticed that .docx file are displayed with a dark background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKUDQ.png)

This prove that there must be a way to tell Windows 10 to do the same with other type of files, but I have no idea where to even start. Maybe there's something in the Registry somewhere? Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Thanks to everyone in advance and thanks for your attention.

Comment: Try affecting the look of Windows Explorer with Settings, Personalization, Colors, and work in the Light / Dark choices.  There is not a setting in File Explorer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to the question.
Step 1: Run the Regedit program 
Step 2: Navigate to: Computer -> HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Control Panel -> Colors 
Step 3: Double click on Window 
Step 4: Type in a RGB color... 

The color format is: Red Green Blue 
The default is 255 255 255, which in hex is FF FF FF, or in normal context is: FFFFFF, or in a formal context: 0xFFFFFF 

So if you want it to be Red, you would type in: 255 0 0 

Here's a great place to figure out themed colors: 
https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel 

You can take those hex numbers and convert to integer numbers. 

Here's why this works. 
The preview pane in the file explorer is actually the notepad program. 
If you change the font in notepad and close notepad, you'll notice that the font also is changed in the preview pane. 
If you change the window color of notepad, then you also change the color of this preview window, and you also change the color of the window color of most programs in windows.